# Ag-Grid multi sort columns without key

Tags: angular, html, ag-grid

I have implemented sorting of the the selected items in AG-Grid on a button click other than header click. 
Ag grid by default needs a `ctrl/shift` key to be pressed while selecting multiple columns. I want to override this behavior and use the above button as flag instead of key press.

Is it possible to do this? I do not want `Pinned` rows.

Comment: `Ag-Grid` community no longer seems to be very active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some hack and made it work.

```js
/*onGridReady of ag-grid options*/
onGridReady: () => this.agHeaderClickListener()



    /** This function adds listener to Ag grid header click event for all columns */
    agHeaderClickListener() {
        console.log( this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ag-header-cell-label'));
        let nodeList =  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ag-header-cell-label');
            for (let node of nodeList) {
                /** IE Fix */
               if (node.addEventListener) {
                   node.addEventListener('click', this.selectionChanged.bind(this));
               } else {
                   node.attachEvent('onclick', this.selectionChanged.bind(this));
               }
            }
      }
```

use the `selectionChanged(event: any)` to do the logical changes you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ag-grid sorting API. It is documented [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#sorting-api). Using this you can update the sort model on button click.

Comment: That is already done. I want to multi sort without shift button by clicking the headers. I used `onSortChanged()` but when the data is present, its being called infinite times which is bad.